# Copying value of last column per row in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy the last column value per row in a worksheet (even if there are blanks). The current code I have right now is able to copy the last column as long as there are no blanks. Pasting the code below:

```
Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastrow
    Range("a" & i).End(xlToRight).Copy
    Range("a" & i).End(xlToLeft).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next i
```

I need A2 to copy the last column value of its raw, which is in D2 (Email). A3 will then copy the last column value of its row which is C3 (Email)

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Was able to get the answer..posting the code below. Thanks BigBen for the help.

```
Sub range1()
Dim i, a, lrow, lcol As Long
Dim rng As range

lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lrow
    lcol = Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Cells(i, "a") = Cells(i, lcol).Value
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with formulae alone:

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),SUMPRODUCT(MAX(COLUMN(B2:F2)*(B2:F2<>""))))),"")
```

where that formula is pasted in A2 and filled down all the yellow cells:

[image]

If you really want to use VBA you can still use a formula and just paste values to avoid all the looping!

```
Sub eh()
Dim lRow As Long: lRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & lRow).Formula = _
    "=IFERROR(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),SUMPRODUCT(MAX(COLUMN(B2:F2)*(B2:F2<>""""))))),"""")"
Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & lRow).Value2 = Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & lRow).Value2
End Sub
```

Although one thing that confuses me is how your `lastRow` calculation gets the last row in column A when column A hasn't been populated yet...

Comment: The lastRow will only work if there is a value at the end of column A so I just put a random value there. In reality though, this is just a portion of an entire project I'm working on and that always has data throughout the end.

Comment: Side note: probably better to avoid indirect as it is volatile.